# Taking part of connection string from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I've tried to build a connection string to a firebird db based on some XML file containing server IP address.

```
public class globals
{
    static string _serv;
    public static string serv
    {
        get
        {
            return _serv;
        }
        set
        {
            _serv=value;
        }
    }
    public static XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();

    public static void serv_check()
    {
        xmld.Load("ustawienia.xml");
        globals._serv = xmld.GetElementsByTagName("ip").Item(0).InnerText;
        if (globals._serv.Length<=0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie zdefiniowano servera");
            Server_Deff sdf = new Server_Deff();
            sdf.ShowDialog();               
        }
    }

    static string db_user = "SYSDBA";
    static string db_pass = "masterkey";

    public static string cstr=
                "User=" + globals.db_user + ";" +
                "Password=" + globals.db_pass + ";" +
                "Database=db_kanc;" +
                "DataSource=" + globals.serv +
                "Port=3050;" +
                "Dialect=3;" +
                "Charset=NONE;" +
                "Role=appka;" +
                "Connection lifetime=15;" +
                "Pooling=true;" +
                "MinPoolSize=0;" +
                "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
                "Packet Size=8192;" +
                "ServerType=0";

    public static FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(globals.cstr);
    public static FbTransaction transaction;


    public static void openConnection() // Open database Connection
    {
    conn.Open();
    transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
}
```

For some reasons neither when the IP address is defined in XML file nor when it's not variable serv seems to be null. I can get the value through message box but not as a proper Datasource in connection string.

While trying to connect to db I'm getting error like this:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: Unable to complete network request to host "Port=3050". ---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: Unable to complete network request to host "Port=3050".
   w FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsConnection.Connect()
   w FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateManagedDatabase(FbConnectionString options)
   w FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateDatabase(FbConnectionString options)
   w FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Every part of the connection string in your code is being terminated by a `;` except for the `DataSource`, where you've failed to add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

```
Unable to complete network request to host "Port=3050"
```

Segment of the **cstr**

```
"DataSource=" + globals.serv +
"Port=3050;" +
```

It means the globals.serv is just an empty string. 
The root cause is serv_check() is run after **cstr** initialize and **cstr** not updated.

If you need to change the **globals.serv** you also need to update **cstr** or just make a new readonly property (Note the ";" after DataSource was added)

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
  get
  {
    return "User=" + globals.db_user + ";" +
                "Password=" + globals.db_pass + ";" +
                "Database=db_kanc;" +
                "DataSource=" + globals.serv + ";" +
                "Port=3050;" +
                "Dialect=3;" +
                "Charset=NONE;" +
                "Role=appka;" +
                "Connection lifetime=15;" +
                "Pooling=true;" +
                "MinPoolSize=0;" +
                "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
                "Packet Size=8192;" +
                "ServerType=0";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class globals
{
    public static string serv { get; set; }
    // other variables here
}

public static XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();

public static void serv_check()
{
    xmld.Load("ustawienia.xml");
    globals._serv = xmld.GetElementsByTagName("ip").Item(0).InnerText;
    if (globals._serv.Length<=0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nie zdefiniowano servera");
        Server_Deff sdf = new Server_Deff();
        sdf.ShowDialog();               
    }
}

static string db_user = "SYSDBA";
static string db_pass = "masterkey";

public static string cstr = string.Format(
    "User={0};Password={1};Database=db_kanc;DataSource={2};Port=3050;" +
        "Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=appka;Connection lifetime=15;" +
        "Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;" +
        "ServerType=0;",
    globals.db_user,
    globals.db_pass,
    globals.serv);

public static FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(globals.cstr);
public static FbTransaction transaction;

public static void openConnection() // Open database Connection
{
    conn.Open();
    transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code fixes?  Code only answers are considered low quality. e.g. Using the String Format to create the connection string makes it easier to see what the final result looks lile.

Comment: It's not the _Format()_ method; it's a missing semicolon. I reckon using the _Format()_ method may have highlighted the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
public class globals
{
static string db_user = "SYSDBA";
static string db_pass = "masterkey";
public static string host;

    public static XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();

    public static string serv_check()
    {
        xmld.Load("ustawienia.xml");
        host = xmld.GetElementsByTagName("ip").Item(0).InnerText;
        if (host.Length<=0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie zdefiniowano servera");
            Server_Deff sdf = new Server_Deff();
            sdf.ShowDialog();
        }
        return host;
    }
    public static string serv=serv_check().ToString();


    public static string cstr
    {
        get
        { return
                "User=" + globals.db_user + ";" +
                "Password=" + globals.db_pass + ";" +
                "Database=db_kanc;" +
                "DataSource=" + globals.serv + ";" +
                "Port=3050;" +
                "Dialect=3;" +
                "Charset=NONE;" +
                "Role=appka;" +
                "Connection lifetime=15;" +
                "Pooling=true;" +
                "MinPoolSize=0;" +
                "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
                "Packet Size=8192;" +
                "ServerType=0";
        }
    }

    public static FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(globals.cstr);
    public static FbTransaction transaction;


    public static void openConnection() // Open database Connection
    {
    conn.Open();
    transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
    }


    public static void closeConnection() // database connection close
    {
        transaction.Commit();
        conn.Close();
    }




    public static int user_id = new int();
    public static int user_r = new int();

}
```

Maybe not the purest solution but works for me :)
Thanks Eric!